# Tomcat 8 session persistence after kill -9 <PID>

Tags: java, session, tomcat, kill-process

I am trying to understand the tomcat's (version 8.0.21) session persistence after I execute kill -9 . When I start my tomcat ( using startup.sh), I observe (randomly) http sessions of my web app ( which were created before the kill command execution) still being maintained.
I understand this session persistence across restart, if I execute shutdown.sh to stop the tomcat and then bring the tomcat up again. My understanding of kill -9  is some what similar to 'power-off'. So my question is :

1. Whether the standard manager implementation gets invoked just after kill -9, which tries to persist session before termination.
2. Or I just get the previous session because my tomcat may have serialized the few session, (somewhere into its temp directory) while it was up earlier (before execution of kill -9).

Comment: On SIGKILL no such methods should be called (that is only applicable for SIGTERM).

Comment: Please, you should always state which version of Tomcat you are using. I don't know for sure, but the behaviour can certainly change between versions.

Answer (score 1):

The [Tomcat session manager documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/manager.html) has lots to say on the topic. Here's a few relevant gems:

> Tomcat provides two standard implementations of Manager for use — the default one stores active sessions, while the optional one stores active sessions that have been swapped out (in addition to saving sessions across a restart of Tomcat) in a storage location...
>
> ...
>
> Whenever Apache Tomcat is shut down normally and restarted, *or when an application reload is triggered*, the standard Manager implementation will attempt to serialize all currently active sessions...

Emphasis mine - I think it's important to note that active sessions get serialized when you reload applications. If you've reloaded the application recently, and then do a `kill -9` (which, as correctly noted in the comments, gives Tomcat no warning and no time to clean anything up, and thus should only be done as a last resort), then you will indeed see sessions persisting across the restart.

It is also possible that you may have the persistent storage manager configured:

> In addition to the usual operations of creating and deleting sessions, a `PersistentManager` has the capability to swap active (but idle) sessions out to a persistent storage mechanism, as well as to save all sessions across a normal restart of Tomcat.

Though I will say that unless you did this configuration, or this install of Tomcat was preconfigured for you, this would not be the case.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I never configured persistent manager myself in tomcat.